# Store user/pass from user created account?

Tags: java, persistence

I'm working on a blank program that will allow a user to create an account so they can store their balance and withdraw/deposit. Once the user enters the username and password, how can I store this information so that the user can log in and see their balance? I"m not necessarily trying to make this so it is extremely secure, I just want to be able to store account information and be able to access it later.

This is the class where they will create the account (still a work in progress):

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class CreateAccount extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    JLabel username = new JLabel("Enter your username");
    JTextField enterUsername = new JTextField(null, 15);
    JLabel password = new JLabel("Enter your password");
    JPasswordField enterPassword = new JPasswordField(null, 15);
    JLabel passwordConfirm = new JLabel("Confirm your password.");
    JPasswordField enterConfirmPassword = new JPasswordField(null, 15);
    JButton okButton = new JButton("OK");

    public CreateAccount() {

        add(username);
        add(enterUsername);
        add(password);
        add(enterPassword);
        add(passwordConfirm);
        add(enterConfirmPassword);
        add(okButton);

        okButton.addActionListener(this);

        setTitle("New Bank Account Creation");
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(270, 300);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        char[] pass = enterPassword.getPassword();
        String passString = new String(pass);
        char[] passConfirm = enterConfirmPassword.getPassword();
        String passStringConfirm = new String(passConfirm);

        String userName = enterUsername.getText();

        if (e.getSource() == okButton) {
            if (!passString.equals(passStringConfirm) || userName.equals(null) || passString.equals(null) || passStringConfirm.equals(null)) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Entered an invalid username or password!");
                enterUsername.setText("");
                enterPassword.setText("");
                enterConfirmPassword.setText("");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the account class which I would like these accounts to be stored as:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class Account {
    private String name;
    private double balance;

    public Account(String name, double balance) {
        getName();
        getBalance();
        this.name = name;
        this.balance = balance;

    }
    String getName() {
        return name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your name?");
    }
    double getBalance() {
        String userBalance = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How much money would you like to deposit?");
        return balance = Double.parseDouble(userBalance);
    }
    public void setName() {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void setBalance() {
        this.balance = balance;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, you should use a database. For a simple application, you can use embedded databases such as HSQL, H2 or Derby. You could then easily migrate to MySQL, MariaDB, or PostgreSQL with exactly the same API if your needs grew later.

JDBC is not exactly a very nice API, but is extremely portable, but you could considere looking at JPA which has some good implementation such as Hibernate, EclipseLink or OpenJPA if you want to store more than use information.

And I almost forget, good practices recommend to store only the hash of the password, never the plain text version ...

Answer (score 1):

use a file which contains the user information. For a bank application which contains multiple attributes for a user, i recommend use an excel sheet since you are nt concerning about security.

[ApachePOI](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/index.html) library will work great in editing excel documents.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are new to Java and therefore probably do not want to be bothering with database or 3rd party libraries at this stage. You can do this using simple text files.

Firstly, let's remove any UI code from the Account class. This is a domain object and should operate on data passed from your UI.

```
public class Account {
    private String userName;
    private double balance;

    public Account(String userName, double balance) {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    public double getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    public void withdraw(double amount){
        //check balance >= amount
        balance -= amount;
    }

    public void deposit(double amount){
        balance += amount;
    }

    public void getUserName(){
        return userName;
    }
}
```

Let's assume for now a user can have only one account and that each user already has an existing account record. On successful login we will read their balance from a property file.

So we will create the files up front:

- c:\bank-data\users.txt

which will have two lines:

```
user1=password
user2=password
```

and

- c:\bank-data\accounts\user1.txt
- c:\bank-data\accounts\user2.txt

each of which will have one line:

```
balance=1000.00
```

To validate we will call the following with the entered details:

```
private boolean authenticate(String userName, String password) throws Exception{

    File userFile = new File("c:/bank-data/users.txt");
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(userFile);
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.load(in);
    String storedPassword = properties.getProperty(userName));
    in.close();

    return password.equals(storedPassword);
}
```

On successful login then we will call the following method which will load the relevant file for the given user name, read the balance and return a new Account initialized with the balance.

```
private Account onLogin(String userName) throws Exception{

    //base data directory
    File database = new File("c:/bank-data");

    //file per user under base data directory
    File accountFile = new File(database, userName + ".txt");

    if(accountFile.exists()){
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(accountFile);
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(in);
        double balance = Double.parseDouble(properties.getProperty("balance"));
        in.close();

    }else{
        //handle new account
    }

    return new Account(userName, balance);
}
```

After calling this method you should then be able to show the user their balance. Saving after some withdrawals/deposits is a simple case of writing the properties back out.

http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/